# Background Service in .net core 3 that will wait for jobs to be processed from JobQueue table in the Database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi, backgroundworker, asp.net-core-3.1

We have to expose a Web API with methods that will perform bulk operations like insert , update and delete, now for example the client will send a request to Create method in the API and they can send upto 100 records at a time in one call, which may take 5 to 6 mins to complete so to avoid gateway timeout we will accept the client's request and send 202 response and insert the request payload in our database table which is called JobQueue, now since the client can send many request one after the other we are thinking to add one background service which will take the data one after the other from JobQueue table , take necessary actions and then send back the notification to client whether it was success or failure, this is what we are thinking to implement.

Now the problem , as i was going through the background service documentation it says the background service starts immediately as soon as the application starts, like there is no on-demand control over the background service to start , stop and resume , can anyone help me with this kind of idea that when an API controller inserts the Job in the Queue table it should trigger the service to start processing of job, like how do i indicate my service that the table might have new items to process, if it isn't already running. Or is there any other idea by which we can achieve this

We cannot use AWS Queue and AWS lambda or Azure Service Bus and Azure functions.

I was initially thinking to use AWS Queue and lambda functions but we cannot use them.

Comment: When a dedicated message queue isn't an option then maybe hangfire jobs are an option.

Comment: Take a look at [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/). It runs as service worker in an existing asp core server and as storage it can use SQL server or redis cache.

Answer (score 0):

The [Heartbeat pattern](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/851944/The-Heartbeat-Pattern) seems to be a good option for you. The central element of the heartbeat pattern is the heartbeat loop, that's doing the following:

- it is an infinite loop, so it's something like a `while(true)`
- it checks whether all the available slots (you can decide to run a single job at a time, or more, maybe 10 jobs at a time) are still having running jobs
- if some jobs have successfully completed, then it marks those jobs as completed and tries to pop as many jobs from the job queue as the number of slots it supports and if the job queue has some jobs to be processed, then the heartbeat loop starts them
- at the end of each iteration of the heartbeat loop, it waits for a while, for instance it could sleep for a second, while the worker thread(s) is/are being processed

Now, since you have client requests to wait for these jobs, it clearly seems to be the case that you might solve this in some manner. Either you have a completed_jobs table and your request API adds the job to the jobqueue and polls this new table, in which case your heartbeat loop would be responsible to remove jobs from the job queue and add them to the completed jobs table once they are completed, or, you could have an internal messaging module, like your request handle may listen to messages on a certain port and the heartbeat would send the success messages to this port via a callback upon completion.

From the perspective of the client-side, this would look like a simple request-response scenario. From the API's point of view, a request is being received from the client-side, a heartbeat job is being scheduled by the creation of a job queue record and it needs to wait until the job is completed. Here somehow the API finds out that the job has been completed (polling the db or direct message from the heartbeat) and then proceeds to parse the result and send a response to the client-side.

Naturally, if you allow several jobs to be processed at a time, like 5 jobs, for example, then you need to use threading to run them at the same time.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, i will try it out and let you know the results

Comment: @Che10 happy to help. I have implemented this pattern a few years ago as well, so if you stumble into difficulties, then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use an [`AutoResetEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.autoresetevent), an [iterator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/iterators), and a [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) loop. I will assume that the records are represented by `int` IDs, and the data-access API has this shape:

```
IEnumerable<int> GetUnprocessedRecords();
bool SetStatusProcessing(int id);
void SetStatusProcessed(int id);
```

Here is my suggestion for the background service:

```
AutoResetEvent mre = new(initialState: false);

IEnumerable<int> Iterator()
{
    while (true)
    {
        foreach (int id in GetUnprocessedRecords())
            yield return id;
        mre.WaitOne();
    }
}

Partitioner<int> partitioner = Partitioner.Create(Iterator(),
    EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering);

ParallelOptions options = new() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 };

Parallel.ForEach(partitioner, options, id =>
{
    if (!SetStatusProcessing(id)) return;
    /* Here process the record */
    SetStatusProcessed(id);
});
```

And whenever you insert more records in the database, you follow with this line:

```
mre.Set();
```

The `Parallel.ForEach` loop takes items from the `Iterator`, without buffering. The iterator yields all the records that have been fetched from the database, and then blocks until the `AutoResetEvent` is signaled.

The `Parallel.ForEach` will utilize permanently a number of `ThreadPool` threads equal to the [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism) configuration, even when the loop is idle. This is not ideal, but it's not a big deal either, provided that the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` is small. It would be possible to avoid blocking threads if you were targeting the .NET 6, so that you could use the newer [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) API, combined with the [`AsyncAutoResetEvent`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/AsyncAutoResetEvent.cs) component from the [AsyncEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx/) library.

There is no provision for terminating gracefully the loop. The `Parallel.ForEach` loop will terminate when the ASP.NET process terminates.

The `SetStatusProcessing` API is expected to be atomic. It should set the status of the record in the database as "Processing", but only if the current status of the record is "Unprocessed", and return `true` only if the status changed. This is a safety precaution for the scenario that the background service happens to run concurrently on more than one processes. I don't know if this is possible, but better safe than sorry. Most likely you don't want to process the same record more than once.

At the database level you could implement the atomic update with an SQL command like this:

```sql
UPDATE JobQueue SET Status = 1 WHERE Id = @Id AND Status = 0;
```

...and return `true` if the `recordsAffected` is greater than zero.

Comment: thank you for this idea i will definitely look into this approach and will let you know the results